# c++: sprintf directly to ostream

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make sprintf write the result directly to a given ostream?

I need this because I have code that does thousands of calls per second to `sprintf` in which the buffer copied into an ostream:

```
while(..)
{
   ..
   char buf[64];
   sprintf(buf, ..)
   oss << buf;
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Of course, your profiler has identified that this is a severe bottleneck for your application, hasn't it? Let alone that you should be using `snprintf` in the first place...

Comment: Absolutely no way? Not even any back_inserter/ostream_iterator clever tricks ?

Comment: @GabiMe Any `std::back_inserter` implementation I can imagine would need to do nearly the same as you are showing in you sample. So the chances gaining better performance from such is arguable.

Comment: You should not attempt to mix C and C++ stdlib APIs. They are not intended to work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do it, but you surely don't need it.

`ostream` **was specifically designed to avoid printf-like formatting**, so I believe any printf/sprintf format output can be redesigned to operate directly on an `ostream`. Just use the [<< overloaded operato](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)r to do your formatting.

Comment: Sure, (you mean the << operator. Not the >>..) but anyway I wanted to know if the there is a way using sprintf

Comment: you don't like the temporary buffer for performances reasons or is it just a style issue?

Comment: Performance wise. There are a lot of coping of big buffers to the ostream thousands of times a seconds, which could be eliminated if there was a way..

Comment: then I recommend to use the << operator, it's way more performant than using a temporary buffer and having to deal with potentially unsafe sprintf functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, C functions have no common with stl containers.

Why not eliminate sprintf at all and put all output directly to stringstream:

```
ss << " some string " << 99 << ...
```

stringstream has no less formatting possibilities that sprintf and you get ready string then:

```
ss.str()
```